# make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am trying to make a file using **make -f Makefile** but I am getting this error:

```
root@kevin-VirtualBox:/home/kevin/Desktop/makef# sudo -s make -f Makefile
gcc -c -o obj/main.o main.c -I./
make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 127
```

--
Make file code:

```
IDIR =./
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =./

LIBS=-lgd -lrt

_DEPS = main.h Makefile
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o serial.o fb.o menu_main.o timer.o cmdin.o buzzer.o statemachine.o inout.o network.o text_file_input.o text_file_input_oven.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Error after running the gcc program:

```
root@kevin-VirtualBox://home/kevin/Desktop/makef# make -f Makefile
gcc -c -o obj/main.o main.c -I./
make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 127
root@kevin-VirtualBox://home/kevin/Desktop/makef# make -f Makefile
gcc -c -o obj/main.o main.c -I./
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 127
root@kevin-VirtualBox://home/kevin/Desktop/makef# mv gcc gcOld^C
root@kevin-VirtualBox://home/kevin/Desktop/makef# make -f Makefile
gcc -c -o obj/main.o main.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/serial.o serial.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/fb.o fb.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/menu_main.o menu_main.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/timer.o timer.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/cmdin.o cmdin.c -I./
cmdin.c: In function ‘processcmd’:
cmdin.c:65:4: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
gcc -c -o obj/buzzer.o buzzer.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/statemachine.o statemachine.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/inout.o inout.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/network.o network.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/text_file_input.o text_file_input.c -I./
text_file_input.c: In function ‘text_file_input’:
text_file_input.c:43:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
text_file_input.c:44:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
text_file_input.c:45:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
text_file_input.c:175:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
gcc -c -o obj/text_file_input_oven.o text_file_input_oven.c -I./
text_file_input_oven.c: In function ‘text_file_input_oven’:
text_file_input_oven.c:43:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
text_file_input_oven.c:44:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
text_file_input_oven.c:45:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
text_file_input_oven.c:112:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
gcc -o main obj/main.o obj/serial.o obj/fb.o obj/menu_main.o obj/timer.o obj/cmdin.o obj/buzzer.o obj/statemachine.o obj/inout.o obj/network.o obj/text_file_input.o obj/text_file_input_oven.o -I./ -lgd -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgd
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have execute permission to the `gcc` executable. What does `which gcc` show, and what are the permissions on that file?

Comment: kevin@kevin-VirtualBox://usr/bin$ ls gcc -l total 4
drwxrwxrwx 5 kevin kevin 4096 Dec 27 19:23 arm-linux-gnueabi

Comment: Why are you showing the permissions of a directory named `arm-linux-gnueabi`, not the `gcc` executable?

Comment: sorry this is the the gcc folder 'drwxrwxrwx 3 kevin  kevin      4096 Dec 27 19:22 gcc'

Comment: I didn't ask for permissions of the folder, I asked for permissions of the `gcc` program itself.

Comment: You shouldn't have a folder `gcc` in the first place. Where is it located?

Comment: oky the gcc folder is located in //usr/bin - if i run the  gcc program i get some other errors (added to the question)

Comment: the gcc program 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb 11 11:59 gcc -> gcc-4.6
'

Comment: Do you have package libgd-dev installed?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you searched all files/directories named gcc, checked where the executable is, and how it replies on version request. You can run these commands: which gcc; gcc --version; find / -name gcc -exec ls -ld {} 2>/dev/null \;

Comment: I see you have VirtualBox, according to my experience, build under a shared folder may trigger some uncertain problem, so if you are using a shared folder, please copy the source tarball to a non-shared folder of your guest OS, then untar it then build.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't installed the full Development tools.
I encountered the same issue and solved it by installing the Development tools (including gcc)

yum groupinstall "Development Tools"