# Weird error when trying to install a module using cpan on a RedHat

Tags: perl, redhat, cpan

When I am trying to install any module on a RedHat 7.3 using `cpan`, I am getting this weird message - "`make: execvp: true: Permission denied`":

```
sudo cpan
cpan[1]> install Log::Log4perl
...
(tests run ok)
...
Running make install
make: execvp: true: Permission denied
make: *** [blibdirs] Error 127
  MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz
  sudo /bin/make install  -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz            : install NO
```

Then, if I navigate to the cpans `build_dir` (from `MyConfig.pm`), find the folder with this module, and run `make test; sudo make install` there - everything runs fine.

What is wrong with `cpan` there? How this could be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

If you're installing the module into the system library, you can probably save yourself considerable pain by installing the pre-build RPM package.

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Log-Log4perl
```

Comment: For `Log::Log4perl` this will work, but not every module is supplied as an RPM. For example, for `sudo yum install Text::Xslate` this, sadly, won't work (at least with my configuration).

Comment: @Basil Your question wasn't about `Text::Xslate`.

Comment: `perl-Text-Xslate` exists in some CentOS repos.

Answer (score 3):

`make: execvp: foo: Permission denied` [happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089807/make-execvp-gcc-permission-denied) when `foo` is some program that does not have execute permission. Find the `true` program in your `$PATH` (typically `/bin/true` or `/usr/bin/true`, but maybe there's another one if you have an idiosyncratic `$PATH`) and make sure you have execute permission for it.

Comment: `sudo which true` -> `/bin/true`; `sudo ls -ld /bin/true` -> `-rwxr-xr-x`. Hmm, seems that I do have execute permission for it.